Whatsapp messages all lost, no back up on phone. S20 phone too new to use recovery method suitable for OS9 and below. Feel gutted, any ideas?
Whatsapp messages all lost, no back up on phone.  S20 phone too new to use recovery method suitable for OS9 and below. Feel gutted, any ideas?

Do you have any backup, like local backup files or Google Drive backup? Without any of them, it's impossible to restore anything because WhatsApp doesn't store backups on its server.
